# aligning divs of different sizes. I check and didn't find this situation

Tags: html, css

When I change the height of the 5 rectangle the 4th rectangle changes height too. The fifth rectangle is supposed to be smaller and centered vertically on the end of the 4. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

```css
.rack1 {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 925px;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rack2 {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 925px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.network {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.jstatus {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.power {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 60px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.scd {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 20px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board6 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board5 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board4 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board3 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board2 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board1 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.cluster {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.cooler {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 60px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
#header {
  background-color: #F00;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#content {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(images/grid.png);
  height: auto;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #8b8b8b;
}
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-image: url(images/grid.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack2">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack2">
        <div class="network"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you seriously need all that code to exemplify your issue? I bet you can cut 80% of it so that someone can read it easily. thanks

Comment: I have  one row of 5 divs, the div on the far right is supposed to be smaller and vertically aligned center... When I change the size or create a margin or even pad another div inside to get the same effect, it changes the attributes on the 4th div. If you can't help me, pass on the question. Will eventually figure it out, but thought i would ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very vague and without the comments this would of been impossible but I assume this is what you are looking for. Your using the class "rack2" for both the 4th and 5th column and when you modify it, it modifies the attributes of both columns. Adding a third class "rack3" and modifying it's attributes would be the easiest solution. Also you are modifying padding when you should be modifying the margins.

```css
.rack1 {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 925px;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rack2 {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 925px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .rack3 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 240px;
   margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.network {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.jstatus {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.power {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 60px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.scd {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 20px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board6 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board5 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board4 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board3 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board2 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.board1 {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.cluster {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.cooler {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  height: 60px;
  width: 228px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
#header {
  background-color: #F00;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#content {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(images/grid.png);
  height: auto;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #8b8b8b;
}
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-image: url(images/grid.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack1">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack2">
        <div class="network"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="scd"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="power"></div>
        <div class="board6"></div>
        <div class="board5"></div>
        <div class="board4"></div>
        <div class="board3"></div>
        <div class="board2"></div>
        <div class="board1"></div>
        <div class="cluster"></div>
        <div class="cooler"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rack3">
        <div class="network"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks, been writing java for 3 days for a roll out and sometimes you don't see the obvious... i didn't insult anyone either... I just wanted to meet someone to help me, people that are critics and offer no help are a waste of my time. Thank you...

Comment: No problemo, we have all been there.